# Code not checking if inputted answer is correct

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a multiple choice quiz that takes questions from an external .txt file and prints it in python. The text file is laid out like this:

1,Who was the first man to walk on the moon?,A.Michael Jackson,B.Buzz Lightyear,C.Neil Armstrong,D.Nobody,C

When I run the code and input the right answer it still says incorrect but continues to say the answer I inputted.

In the code I split each line in the text file by a ',' so the correct answer in the text file is always detail[6]. In the code I have put:

```py
if answer.upper() == detail[6]:
            print("Well done, that's correct!")
            score=score + 1
            print(score)
elif answer.upper() != detail[6]:
            print("Incorrect, the correct answer is ",detail[6])
            print(score)
```

I thought this would work as it is checking the inputted answer against detail[6] but it always comes out as incorrect.

```py
import random
score=0
with open('space_quiz_test.txt') as f:
    quiz = f.readlines()
questions = random.sample(quiz, 10)    
for question in questions:
    detail = question.split(",")
    print(detail[0],detail[1],detail[2],detail[3],detail[4],detail[5])
    print(" ")
    answer=input("Answer: ")
    while True:
            if answer.upper() not in ('A','B','C','D'):
                print("Answer not valid, try again")
            else:
                break
    if answer.upper() == detail[6]:
        print("Well done, that's correct!")
        score=score + 1
        print(score)
    elif answer.upper() != detail[6]:
        print("Incorrect, the correct answer is ",detail[6])
        print(score)
```

I would like the code to be able to check if the inputted answer is correct by checking it against detail[6] within the text file, instead of always coming out as incorrect, the correct answer is detail[6].

Comment: Since you didn't tell us what `detail[6]` *is*, how could we tell why it doesn't agree with `answer.upper()` (especially because you didn't tell us what that was either). Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman so with the example given of the text file layout, detail[6] would be C. The answer.upper() will also be C as this is the correct answer.

Comment: If you run `print(detail[6])` does it print C, or does it print something else? It is unlikely that Python is wrong about the truth value of `answer.upper() == detail[6]`. In any event, why not give a [mcve]? Something that we can directly run, reproducing the problem?

Comment: When I run the code and input the correct answer it gives me this ```Answer: B
Incorrect, the correct answer is  B``` so it knows what the correct answer is it just doesnt seem to be checking it

Comment: Im not too sure how to give you an example to reproduce the problem without giving you the .txt file to get the questions from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `readlines()` retains the newline character at the end of each line.
Your `detail[6]` is something like `'C\n'` rather than `'C'` itself. To fix that, use

```
detail = question.strip().split(",")
```